# Greatest and smallest value of a function in boundaries.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this function:
$$f(x,y)=x^3+3y^3-x^2-4y$$
I had to find the local extrema. Taking the first and second derivatives I found extrema at (0,2/3) and (1,2/3). From the second derivatives of for (0,2/3) the signs differ so there is no maximum or minimum there. For (1,2/3) both derivatives are greater than 0, so I got a minimum. 
Now I am asked to find the greatest and the lowest value of the function in D where 
$$D:0\le y\le1$$$$y\le x\le 1 $$. I am not sure how to proceed at this point. Since I found that (1,2/3) is a minimum and it's included in this region, it should have the lowest value. How do I find the greatest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that your local minimum is necessarily the lowest value in the region. For instance, this function has a local max at the origin, but then has higher values at the corners:[image: It's actually the same value at the corners, but the picture looks good]

This means you'll need to test the values of your function on the boundaries for both minimums and maximums. Your region is a triangle; on one edge you can set $x=1$, on another you can set $x = y$, and on the last you can set $y=0$. This turns $f$ into a single-variable function, and you can use your calculus 1 min/max testing. Finally, test at your three corners.

Comment: So in the f(x,y) I input the boundary values. I get 3 different functions. I take derivatives of them to find extrema. And then I take second derivatives to see if it's minimum or maximum and it's value and compare the results?

Comment: That's right. Remember that these functions have boundaries too, so you only need to check a certain range of values.

Comment: I noticed and corrected a mistake in my answer. I said that one of the boundaries was $x=0$. That was incorrect, you want to test at $x=1$.